# Are Level-2 residuals in a MLM with lmer the same as the Random Intercepts? How to check them for Independence, constant variance and endogeneity?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, residuals, assumptions

I'm using the lmer function of R (lme4) to make a model of the following kind:

`model <- lmer(DV ~ Predictor_categorical + (1|Group_categorical), data = df_data)`

I look at data which is taken over some time, yet I don't expect any dependence on time.

I want to test if the assumptions for a MLM are met. Level 1 Residuals are all clear. Level 2 residuals for me are difficult to understand.

1. Level-2 residuals are independent and not auto-correlated.
2. Level-2 residuals have constant variance.
3. There is no endogeneity at level-2.

My questions basically are: How do I extract the Level-2 residuals from a lmer model? Are the Level-2 residuals (in my case) just the Intercept values that are given by ranef for each factorlevel of Group_categorical? Do I plot them against the fitted(model) to check for constant variance (That plot looks funny and makes no sense to me)? Does auto-correlation have any meaning in my case (where I don't expect time dependency)?

Thanks for all help!